# C# XmlSerializer Deserialize Date format

Tags: c#, postgresql, date, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I need to bring (among others) a date from an XML file to a PostgreSQL table in my C# application.

My problem is that if I declare the field as a string like this:

```
[XmlAttribute("startDate")]
public string StartDate { get; set; }
```

it doesn't get deserialized at all (the value is null). If I declare it as DateTime like this:

```
[XmlAttribute("startDate")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

no matter what I enter into the XML field I always get the value `01.01.0001 00:00:00`.

I tried to enter the date using YYYY-MM-DD, YYYY/MM/DD and DD.MM.YYYY. What am I doing wrong? It works perfectly fine for other strings and integers.

Edit:

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<command name="TestCommand">
  <weeks>11</weeks> <!-- this works fine -->
  <startDate>2017/02/01</startDate> <!-- this doesn't -->
</command>
```

Deserialization happens using XmlSerializer.Deserialize() into an Config file which consists of the fields I gave examples of above

Comment: Can you show example xml and code responsible for deserializtion ?

Comment: have you tried setting `DataType = "date"` in the `XmlAttribute`?

Comment: @JonSkeet - i think the problem is somewhere else. Note that when OP changed data type to string it's being deserialized to null

Comment: @MajkeloDev: That's true - had missed that. There's definitely a lot of information missing here...

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I edited more information into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the answer is simple. This is not XmlAttribute ... this is XmlElement.
Change attribute to:

```
[XmlElement("startDate")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

Are you sure element "weeks" works properly and is marked with XmlAttribute ?

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem! Should I generally use XmlElement in those cases (sounds like "weeks" working was more of a coincidence?)

Comment: Oh, you were right. The other fields were XmlElements. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Look at your xml - name is an ATTRIBUTE on command ELEMENT, but weeks and startDate are elements. Can you see the difference ?